# selecting <div> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I asked here a big question 1 day ago, but didn't get enough good answers, so I divided the question into parts. This is one part:

Have a look at this code:

```
<?php
    foreach($tickets as $key=>$value)
           {
?>
               <div id="topic_<?php echo $key;?>"  data-id="<?php echo $key;?>" onclick="showDetails()">
                   ------------------------------
               </div>
               <div id="details_<?php echo $key;?>"  data-id="<?php echo $key;?>">
                   ------------------------------
               </div>
<?php
           }
?>
```

Here, we have some `<div>`s ("topic_..." and "details_..."), each with unique id(`data-id`). We don't know how much of these `<div>`s will be there, because of the `foreach()` loop. All "details" `<div>`s will be hidden at the first time. Now, what I want, when I click on a "topic" `<div>`, its corresponding "details" `<div>` will be shown. I think I should use a function and call that function in the `onclick` event, that's why I used `onclick="showDetails()"` in the "topic" `<div>`. If I am wrong or you have a better idea, please share with me. Here is the Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#details_").hide();
    });
    function showDetails()
    {
        var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
        $("#details_"+id).show();
    }
</script>
```

I know I couldn't detect all "details_......" `<div>`s here, and may be there are also some problems in the `showDetails()` function. Please help me.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid all of this ID nonsense by using relative selectors.

`showDetails(this)`   <--- send a refernce to the current element

```
function showDetails(element) {
      $(element).next('div').show().
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the source of event to function using `this`.

*Html*

```
<div id="topic_<?php echo $key;?>" 
        data-id="<?php echo $key;?>" onclick="showDetails(this)">
```

*Javascript*

```
function showDetails(obj)
{
    var id=$(obj).attr('data-id');
    $("#details_"+id).show();
}
```

If you bind the event using `jQuery` then you can use `this` inside handler

```
$('[id^=topic_]').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#details_"+id).show();
});
```

Comment: Actually, since he's using jQuery anyhow, shouldn't he use `$(obj).data("id")` to get the data-id?

Answer (score 0):

`$('div[id^=details_]')` will get you all divs where the id starts with the string `details_`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you want to hide all the divs.
Either add a css class like "hidden" and set the display to none or go with jquery with something like this

```
$('div[id^="details_"]').hide();
```

Then, the showDetails function needs to know which item needs to be shown.
Instead of having the `onclick` on every single item, I suggest you use jquery.

*(This is not necessary but is an alternative to what you have)*

```
$('div[id^="details_"]').click(function() {
    $("#details_"+ $(this).attr('data-id')).show();
    // or as Diodeus suggested
    // $(this).next('div').show().
});
```

In sum, you can put all of this in the document ready method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[id^="details_"]').hide();
    $('div[id^="details_"]').click(function() {
        $("#details_"+ $(this).attr('data-id')).show();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is an accordion. Each Topic div is the accordion header, each Details div is the accordion body. When you click on a Topic div its corresponding Details div will open up.
You can easily find a jQuery plugin for accordions that will provide this kind of functionality.

But if you don't want a plugin you could do something like this:

1) Add a class to the topic divs, class="topic"

2) Add a class to the details divs, class="details"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var details = $('div.details');
    var topics = $('div.topics');
    details .hide();        //hide all the details divs
    topics .click(function() {
        details.hide();     //hide any open details    
        $(this).next('div.details').show();   //or you could use slideDown()/fadeIn()
    };
});
```

This code assumes that each topic div will have a details div right after it.
If you don't want the details divs to hide each time you click a topic div, just remove the `details.hide()` line.

Comment: Thanks man. I think there is something like "accordion" in HTML 5, I don't remember it now, that's why I am trying jQuery. Can you tell me about it ? @officert

Comment: There isn't any HTML5 accordion (not that I know of at least ;) ). I've seen some examples of HTML5/CSS3 accordions that use jQuery too. But using jQuery, like in the example I showed, is a very easy and straightforward way to get accordions. If you need more functionality like fancy transitions, or callbacks, etc.. I would look for a jQuery accordion plugin. The jQuery UI library has a good one. I typically just use my own accordion plugin as I like to keep things simple and only have the exact functionality that I need and know exactly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Above and beyond all of these things, you really really really don't need to have onclick inside your divs. Please, just don't do it.

Consider instead something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($tickets as $key=>$value)
       {
?>
           <div id="topic_<?php echo $key;?>"  data-id="<?php echo $key;?>">
               ------------------------------
           </div>
           <div id="details_<?php echo $key;?>"  data-id="<?php echo $key;?>">
               ------------------------------
           </div>
<?php
       }
?>
```

Note that I got rid of onclick... Now, in your js:

```
// set up your doc-ready code...
$(function(){
    var showDetails = function(evt)
    {
        var id= $(this).data('id');
        $("#details_"+id).show();
    };
    // now bind all divs that start with topic_ with a click event, with showDetails as the handler
    $('div[id^=topic_]').on('click',showDetails);
});
```

NOW, great, hunky dory, but can't we get even better than this?? I think we can! If you have the power to choose a tag structure, choose one that gives you nesting as part of its logical semantic markup, so that your markup has meaning...

First, let's choose logical markup:

```
<dl class="topicslist">
<?php
foreach($tickets as $key=>$value)
       {
?>
           <dt data-id="<?php echo $key;?>">
               ------------------------------
           </dt>
           <dd data-id="<?php echo $key;?>">
               ------------------------------
           </dd>
<?php
       }
?>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
.topiclist dd {
    display:none;
    margin:0 0 1em;
    padding:0;
}

.topiclist dd.show {
    display:block;
}
```

JS!

```
// set up your doc-ready code...
$(function(){
    var showDetails = function()
    {
        // find the next sibling dd to this object and show it!
        $(this).next('dd').show();
    };
    // now bind all divs that start with topic_ with a click event, with showDetails as the handler
    $('dl dt').on('click',showDetails);
});
```

It's not too many steps from that to making one function that can also toggle the show/hide!

```
// set up your doc-ready code...
$(function(){
    var toggleDetails = function(){
        var mySib = $(this).next('dd');
        ($(mySib).hasClass('show')) ? $(mySib).removeClass('show') : $(mySib).addClass('show');
    };

    $('.topiclist dt').on('click',toggleDetails);
});
```

With this in mind, really, you don't even need to have the data-id in your markup at all... as long as you always arrange your list so that the dt is first and directly followed by a dd, this should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/nqyRX/

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit? Which way did you try to implement? What errors are you seeing (if any)? Can't really tell you why it's not working without a better idea of how you adapted my advice to your code.