# Showing/Hiding DOM for only one element

Tags: javascript, dom

I basically have multiple elements like this:

```
<tr class="class1">
...
</tr>
<tr class="class1">
...
</tr>
<tr class="class1">
...
</tr>
<tr class="class1">
...
</tr>
```

etc. I want to request the DOM like this:

```
dom.query(".class1").live("click", function() {
    if (dom.query("#div1InsideClass1").is(':visible')) {
        dom.query("#div1InsideClass1").hide();
        ...
    } else {
        dom.query("#div1InsideClass1").show();
        ...
    }
});
```

But the way that this function works is that it does the function for every single instance of the  above, as well as every instance of #div1InsideClass1. Is there a way to detect which particular tr element was clicked on? I heard the .next() function usually helps, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Elements IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: possible duplicate of [selecting <div> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591850/selecting-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You have a root problem: there can't be duplicated ids on your html. You'll need to address that first of all.

Assuming you add a css class to those divs named `div1InsideClass1`, this should do the trick

```
$(".class1").live("click", function() {
    $(this).find('.div1InsideClass1').toggle();
});
```

If you need to keep using the `if` statement, this code is equivalent but allows you to add extra logic within `if else`

```
$(".class1").live("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $div = $this.find('.div1InsideClass1');
    if ($div.is(':visible')) {
        $div.hide();
        ...
    } else {
        $div.show();
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong I think he has some thing like div1InsideClass1 div2InsideClass1 etc